# How to remove frame on RDKit figures?

Tags: python, visualization

RDKit can plot molecules, thought the structures are surrounded by an ugly frame with ticks. How can I turn that off and plot the molecules without that frame?

Note, the `%pylab inline` portion of this code is from the Jupyter environment.

```
%pylab inline
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw

smiles = 'CCC'
m = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
fig = Draw.MolToMPL(m)
title('Test')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `rdkit` and `rdkit`'s `Chem` just use the `matplotlib`. So, if you import `matplotlib` you can edit your figure like any other `matplotlib` figure.

I produced this from the command line, so it may work differently in the Jupyter environment.

It looks like `Chem` doesn't properly scale the drawing based on how large the chemical is, so I added `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim` to make the molecule larger in the frame.

```python
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
smiles = 'CCC'
m = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
fig = Draw.MolToMPL(m)
plt.title('Test')
plt.axis('off')
coord_min = 0.35
coord_max = 0.65
plt.xlim((coord_min, coord_max))
plt.ylim((coord_min, coord_max))
fig.savefig('mol.jpeg', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]